# How can I wait for a function to be called by an unknown caller?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have a callback function that gets called by some other object which I can't control. I need to wait until this callback function is called, I don't care by who.

```
var successFunc = function() {
    // do stuff
}

myObject.onSuccess = successFunc;

// hang on until successFunc is called...
```

I found this hacky workaround, but it sucks:

```
var completed = false;

var successFunc = () => {
    // do stuff
    completed = true;
}

myObject.onSuccess = successFunc;

while (!completed) {
    sleep(200); // sleeps for 200 ms
}
```

Comment: Well you need to use a promise https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise or call the next step inside of your successFunc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a promise, pass its `resolve` function as callback to the unknown caller somehow, listen to the promise's resolution:

```js
let callback;
const promise = new Promise(r => callback = r);

promise.then(() => console.log('unknown caller called'));

setTimeout(function unknownCaller() {
    console.log('randomly calling back');
    callback();
}, Math.random() * 5000);
```